# FIDE rating: how games are rated if a new list is published while playing a tournament

Tags: rating, fide

Does anybody knows how games are rated (FIDE rating) when a new list is published while playing a tournament?

Let's say I'm playing a tournament starting at April and ending at June. Starting ratings are those listed in April list, but before the tournament ends there will be new lists at May and June, and tournament results will be reported at June.

There are several options:

A) All games are rated as players rating were those in April list (the starting ones).

B) All games are rated as players rating were those in June list (when the tournament is reported to FIDE).

C) April games are rated with April ratings, May ones with May ratings, and June ones with June ratings (it seems strange, but it is how it works for Catalan ratings).

I could find no response to this question at [FIDE handbook](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article). The only clue could be article 8.4:

```
8.4
If an unrated player receives a published rating before a particular
tournament in which he has played is rated, then he is rated as a
rated player with his current rating, but in the rating of his
opponents he is counted as an unrated player.
```

which makes me think that all games are rated with the starting ratings (option A).

Comment: downvoters, could you clarify what's wrong with the question?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more details, see below.

Comment: Btw. this is a good question as the answer is not obvious and you apparently searched the Rating Regulations and you even give a comparison to a national rating system. No reason to downvote, I upvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option *A* is correct, option *C* applies to some tournaments, see below.

It is not explicitly stated in the [FIDE Rating Regulations](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=172&view=article) but the practice has always been that for rating purposes the rating valid at the starting date of the tournament is used. The only exception are tournaments that last longer then 90 days which have to be reported for rating every month

> 4.1 For tournaments, a period not greater than 90 days, except:
>
> ```
> 4.11 Leagues may be rated which last for a period greater than 90 days.
> 4.12 The QC may approve the rating of tournaments lasting more than 90 days.
> 4.13 For tournaments lasting more than 90 days, interim results must be reported on a monthly basis.
> ```

This is made more explicit in the [International Title Regulations](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=174&view=article)

> 1.46 Rating of Opponents
>
> ```
> 1.46a The Rating List in effect at the start of the tournament shall be used, see exception 1.15. ...
> ```
>
> 1.15 In tournaments which last longer than 90 days, the opponents’ ratings and titles used shall be those applying when the games were played.

Similar wording as in `1.46a` would probably be helpful in the FIDE Rating Regulations.

Here are two examples:

1. [Sallskapets Jubileums-KM 2016](https://ratings.fide.com/view_source.phtml?code=129872) lasted for exactly 90 days by a rough calculation and you can see that each player's rating is the same in all rounds (click on any player and you can see all their opponents have them with the same rating, the January rating in fact).
2. [1. Bundesliga rounds 10-11](https://ratings.fide.com/view_source.phtml?code=125513) and [1. Bundesliga rounds 14-15](https://ratings.fide.com/view_source.phtml?code=111325) lasts for six months, it is reported every month and each month the current ratings are used.

Comment: in fact I said that in catalan federation C) option applies and actually it depends on rounds timing. If there's a round per week (or slower) then C) applies, but in faster tournaments (daily rounds for example) A) option applies

Comment: Is this the same for county's own rating systems?